# How do you stay alive with Heimerdinger?

Tags: league-of-legends

1. What is the best way to get lots of CS and stay alive with Heimer?  I always defend (not Heimer) turret but I get killed a lot when I overextend.  If I don't place both turrets in lane I don't get any minions.
2. Is it better to buy AP or cooldown reduction for Heimer?  I always buy a lot of cooldown reduction for my towers to replenish and use them a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heimer is one of the hardest champions to kill in lane. I don't play Heimer outside of ARAM but here are some tips I can give you:

**Playing offensively:**

*You can be very aggressive with Heimer and abuse his range and pushing power.*

- Use your turrets to push your lane and put pressure on your opponent
  by making them CS under their tower.
- Level your rockets ASAP, these have fantastic range and do
  significant damage.
- Make sure you ward river, both sides if mid. Keeping your opponent at
  their tower means you are over extended and easily gankable. With
  vision you can avoid unnecessary deaths. You should be ahead of your
  opponent in CS anyway so you will have the gold advantage for these
  wards.
- You want to have lots of mana regen to sustain your casting.

**Playing defensively:**

*Heimer can be a CS whore and -very- difficult to kill if playing defensively*

- Use turrets to grant vision, or place behind you for an escape route
- Use your ult when getting ganked, a significant slow makes ganks very hard
- Keep your grenade on cooldown to make sure any gank attempts on you will blind/stun them.
- Last hit with auto attacks, not towers or rockets, to avoid over extending.
- Cooldown on heimer isn't really necessary for turrets here, they should be lasting quite some time if your opponent or minions can't easily reach them. Concentrating on mana regen or AP is beneficial. Getting gold per 5 items is also a nice idea for this tactic, giving you the edge on gold without having to worry about trading and getting forced out of lane.

Comment: By saying _Last hit with auto attacks, not towers or rockets, to avoid over extending._ you mean to use turrets ONLY for vision and defend in escape route not firing? So it's better that I upgrade my towers in the end if I playing defensively?

Comment: I think it is pretty situational, but yes, leveling towers last is an option.

Comment: Its normal to rush level 3 turrets, and then up to you if you want to get 5 quickly or not.

Comment: In case you didn't know, rushing level 3 is usually done so you can place two turrets. Beyond that the levels are less useful compared to levels in other abilities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good these guys are but they are highly mistaken. This (obviously) is not intended for the original poster but anyone who comes across it.

I'm gonna start with a general overview. Heimerdinger's main strength is his turrets, a lot of people complain that he can't be countered and rage about him being OP. The reason for this is because his counter is (no offence) not being an idiot. If you stray too far from your turrets you are dead, if you stay within your turret range anyone who dives you is dead.

You mainly want to go top lane as there are a wider range of melee champs that you can exploit by running in circles while they tank your turrets. To start you want to place your turrets in lane before the game starts (you can use the texture of the floor to help with placement). Every Time a new creep wave arrives place your new turret behind your melee minions. Max your Q then W then E (with ult whenever available). If you are winning lane go for a Morellonomicon. This will increase your burst and poke potential allowing you to pick up more kills. If not get zhonyas. Your main tactic is poking with W to weaken them if they get inside turret range you stun them immediately (the turret laser is the main damage source). Every time you get an item or level your ult check your ult damage on the W. Unless you are absolutely sure only ult+W on a stunned champ, try to catch them off guard i.e. you do 690 damage and they have 650 health. If you get ganked place your ult+Q and EW the more dangerous champ (the one with more range and speed/gap closing potential). Of course Zhonya in your turrets if you get low. Late game your main focus is pushing turrets. Place your 3 turrets just outside turret range, again the textures on the ground will help. Never use your ult stun. Your other ults are way more worth unless your whole team is really low and you are getting chased by the whole enemy team who all have full health, then you can ult stun. Build a standard AP build. Zhonyas is the most important. My final build is usually- Zhonya, Morellonomicon, Deathcap, Void staff. The last two items are situational, they can be: Boots, Ludens, Liandry's, Rylai's, ROA, Banshee and Guardian Angel is pretty good.

To summarise-
During laning phase stay in turret range.
Use W to finish weakened enemies (they won't know what hit'em)
Your stun is really hard to land but also really hard to dodge.
Don't overextend because half of you is your turrets.
Stay calm when outnumbered and run in circles around your turrets, don't forget Zhonyas.

Final tips-
Use your turrets for ambushes, e.g. fall back when ganked and place them all in a bush or bait someone to walk past your bush of turrets.

Comment: I agree with the first part. Bit about ult - it's really hard to hit with ult+W if your enemy isn't stunned right before you for. For most situations when you are not alone it's best to us ult+E for chasing and ult+Q for running away. Maybe ult+E is not the best damage but if you have some turret ammo always available you can place turret or two and the team do the rest of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

- Chose the side of the mid you want to be (I choose the side of Red depending the jungler)
- Put a turret in this bush
- Max Rocket
- When there is 2 creeps left and the opponent just rocket them 3 :-)
- if the jungle comes troll him a little and w8 he destoys your tower cause he is angry and put an other one :-D

With flash and grenade u can't die :-D

Skill order : 
W-Q-E-W-W-R-W-Q-W-Q-R-Q-Q-E-E-R-E-E

Comment: Why do you need to Max rocket? Grenade does more damage, blinds and more than 50% of my grenades stuns.. Also you can't control rockets so they're useless if you are in fight and some enemy minions are around..

Comment: You don't have to aim rocket, it always hits. Good luck landing those grenades (they are easy to avoid. being so slow)

Comment: If enemy is smart enought to stay behind 3 minions or if it's a team fight ahead enemy minions, rocket NEVER hits champion. Maybe for first times it's better not to upgrade granades but after few plays it's easy to aim grenade :)

Comment: Cause I use grenade just for the CC lvl 1 Stun/blind same as lvl 5 + very slow and not reliable damage .You can miss it not the rockets. On ult you fire 5 Rockets => Team fight in jugnle you can hit the 5 enemies + It can't be dodged and have superior range